XBar stack timestamp
I would like to have a XBar stack where I sum duration formatted in dateplot.
Here is my code so far, I tried with a simple example, adding 30 minutes duration but unfortunately the first 30 minutes doesn't have the same size as other.
Any suggestion on how to fix it ?
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xbar stacked, date coordinates in=x, ytick=\empty, width=\linewidth, height = 3cm, xticklabel={\year-\month-\day\  \hour:\minute}, xtick distance=1/48, date ZERO=2015-09-13 00:00:00]
        \addplot[color=black, fill=yellow] coordinates{(2015-09-13 00:30:00,0)};
        \addplot+[color=black, fill=black] coordinates{(2015-09-13 00:30:00,0)};
        \addplot+[color=black, fill=yellow] coordinates{(2015-09-13 00:30:00,0)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SX!

Your code generates the warnings
Missing character: There is no 0 (U+0030) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 (U+0030) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no : (U+003A) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 (U+0030) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 (U+0030) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no : (U+003A) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 (U+0030) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 (U+0030) in font nullfont!

because date ZERO takes only a day, with format <year>-<month>-<day>. The time 00:00:00 isn't used and generates the warnings.
From the pgfplots manual:

As of version 1.13, the first encountered coordinate is used as date ZERO, i.e. it is assigned automatically without user intervention.
Users will never see the resulting numbers, so one probably never needs to change this value.

So add
\addplot coordinates{(2015-09-13 00:00:00,0)};

at the beginning of your plot.
Example (setting also ymin and ymax to remove the other warning):
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      xbar stacked,
      date coordinates in=x,
      ytick=\empty,
      width=\linewidth,
      height = 3cm,
      xticklabel={\year-\month-\day\  \hour:\minute},
      xtick distance=1/48,
      ymin=-1,
      ymax=1
    ]
    \addplot coordinates{(2015-09-13 00:00:00,0)};
    \addplot[color=black, fill=yellow] coordinates{(2015-09-13 00:30:00,0)};
    \addplot[color=black, fill=black] coordinates{(2015-09-13 00:30:00,0)};
    \addplot[color=black, fill=yellow] coordinates{(2015-09-13 00:30:00,0)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


